# MapQuest ios API unable to request route

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, mapquest

I'm trying to draw a route on a MQMapView. I got the following response on the `routeLoadFinished()` call back in simulator,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response>
<info><statusCode>400</statusCode>
<messages><message>No sessionId found in request. You must provide a sessionId when requesting a Route Shape.</message></messages><copyright>    <imageUrl>http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif</imageUrl><imageAltText>© 2012 MapQuest, Inc.</imageAltText><text>© 2012 MapQuest, Inc.</text></copyright></info><route/></response>
```

I don't know why it says I was requesting a route shape where I'm just trying to get the route drawn via `[self.route getRouteWithStartCoordinate:start endCoordinate:end];`

I'm using licensed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you still seeing this error?  Generally, a status code 400 means that there was a problem with the input, so the service is unable to calculate the route.  Do you think it's possible that there may not be a route between your specified coordinates (i.e., if one of them is in the ocean or a body of water, or away from the road network, etc)?

Disclaimer: I work at MapQuest.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, the coordinates defined in my gpx file was invalid. Corrected the coordinates, the routing is working very well now.

Much appreciated!